# Wiring a switch to toggle both usb power and external power on Arduino

Tags: arduino, power-supply, switches

I have a 5v Arduino Pro Micro. I am using it to run a series of motors. I am controlling it through the USB port. The USB power doesn't supply enough current to power the motors, so I am using a 9v external power supply and a series of transistors etc. I want an on/off switch for my project, but I need it to toggle the power for the 9v power supply and the USB connection at the same time. How could I do this?

Comment: Post your schematic (how you have it wired up). And do you need to switch off the 9v supply at the arduino, or at the power supply?)

Answer (score 2):

Used a double-pole toggle switch (DPDT or DPST) - one pole to switch the USB power, and the second to switch the 9 volts.

Comment: Interesting that might be a good solution. Does anyone know if I cut the power lines of the USB cord leading to the computer so only the data lines are hooked up to the Arduino, will the external power applied to the board drive the USB port and make everything work?